# using awk for reformatting text

Tags: awk, reformat

I have a large file in this format (I have in both csv and text format and the first column is IDs):

```
9   KIDL1   1
9   KIDL1   1
9   KIDL2   0
9   KIDL2   1
9   KIDL3   1
9   KIDL3   1
```

and want to change it to :

```
    KIDL1   KIDL2   KIDL3
9   1/1     0/1     1/1
```

is it possible using awk commands or related programs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Can we ignore first column? Is it always going to be `9`?

Comment: Will there always be two entries per `KIDLn` value per ID like 9?  Will things be in sorted order?  Could there be more than three `KIDLn` values?  Do all keys have the same set of `KIDLn` entries or can it vary?   The short answer to your question is "Yes; Awk can do it".  The long answer says "how hard it is depends on what the full data set looks like" — which means answering the questions I've raised.

Comment: we can not ignore the first column...different IDs continues for hundreds. also the name of second column  varies and not all start with K

Comment: also there is always 2 entries in column 2 per each ID. it is sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution. but I managed to generate the desired output based on input provided.

```
awk '{a[$1" "$2]=$3"/"a[$1" "$2]} END {for (i in a)  {b=b" "i; c=c" "a[i];} {gsub(/ +[0-9]/, " ",b); gsub(/\/ +/, " ",c ) }  print b"\n"$1,c }'
```

Demo:

```
$awk '{a[$1" "$2]=$3"/"a[$1" "$2]} END {for (i in a)  {b=b" "i; c=c" "a[i];} {gsub(/ +[0-9]/, " ",b); gsub(/\/ +/, " ",c ) }  print b"\n"$1,c }' < file1.txt

  KIDL1  KIDL2  KIDL3
9  1/1 1/0 1/1/
$
```